# Different no of tuples for the prediction model and test set data in SVM

Tags: r, svm, predict

I have a dataset with two columns as shown below, where Column 1, timestamp is a particular value for time for which Column.10 gives the total power usage at that instance of time. There are totally 81502 instances for this data.

[image]

I'm doing support vector regression on this data in R using the e1071 package to predict the future usage of power. The code is given below. I first divided the dataset into training and test data. Then using the training data modeled the data using the svm function and then predict the power usage for the testset.

```
    library(e1071)
    attach(data.csv)
    index <- 1:nrow(data.csv)
    testindex <- sample(index,trunc(length(index)/3))
    testset <- na.omit(data.csv[testindex, ])
    trainingset <- na.omit(data.csv[-testindex, ])
    model <- svm(Column.10 ~ timestamp, data=trainingset)
    prediction <- predict(model, testset[,-2])
    tab <- table(pred = prediction, true = testset[,2])
```

However, when I try to make a confusion matrix from the prediction, I'm getting the error:

```
    Error in table(pred = prediction, true = testset[, 2]) : all arguments must have the same length
```

So I tried to find the length of the two arguments and found that

```
    the length(prediction) to be 81502
    and  the length(testset[,2]) to be 27167
```

Since I had done the prediction only for the testset, I don't know how prediction is done for 81502 values. How are the total no of values different for the prediction and the testset? How is the power value for the entire dataset getting predicted eventhough I gave it only for the testset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
prediction <- predict(model, testset[,-2])
```

in

```
prediction <- predict(model, testset)
```

However, you should not use table when doing regression, use the MSE instead.